# Check if element in a list of lists is equal prolog

Tags: prolog

I m trying to check if, in a list of lists, all sublist is equal to the length of the list of lists.

> For example, if I have [[1,2],[3,4]] is true, because I have 2 lists
> of 2 elements.
>
> Otherwise, if I have
>
> [[1],[2,3]] is false because have 2 lists but not all list has 2
> elements
>
> [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]] is false because I have 2 lists and all list have
> 2 elements instead of two

.

I did these two function:

```
count([],0).
count([_H|T],N):-count(T,N1),N is N1+1 .

ma([],0).
ma([H|T],N):- count(H,M1),ma(T,N1), M1 is N1.
```

I did "count" (and work) for count element in a list and return N the number of elements in a list.

The "ma" function doesn't work because "count" is executed until 0, and return 2, after executing ma but until 1 step, and after making directly the M1 is N1, and obviously return false.
I wish to make M1 is N1 at end of the program (like in another programming language, but I think is the then't correct form.

EDIT:

Daniel suggest to use :

```
ma([H],   N) :- length(H, N).
ma([H|T], N) :- length(H, N), ma(T, N).
```

But a list with 3 sublists all with 2 elements gives result 2, instead the result will be false(error) because N number of the list must be equal to N number of elements in ALL Sublist.

I will do on my own, without build-in predicate of prolog.

Comment: My name is Daniel, not David.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a very **basic** solution without built in predicates:

```
count_elements([],N,N).
count_elements([_|T],N,N0):-
    N1 is N+1,
    count_elements(T,N1,N0).

count_length_sub([],_).
count_length_sub([H|T],N):-
    count_elements(H,0,N),
    count_length_sub(T,N).

solve(L):-
    count_elements(L,0,NO),
    count_length_sub(L,NO).

?- solve([[1,2],[3,4]]).
true.

?- solve([[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]).
false.
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I understood the philosophy too!

Comment: Prefer `succ/2` over `... is X+1` because it has more instantiations.

Answer (score 1):

Your `count/2` is like the `length/2` builtin, except that the built-in has more instantiation patterns (try `length(X, Y)` and see). Prefer `length/2`.

You're right that your `ma/2` predicate is unhelpful because 0 is not a length of a sublist. Basically, you've chosen the wrong base case here; your base case should be a list with exactly one item in it:

```
ma_1([H],   N) :- length(H, N).
ma_1([H|T], N) :- length(H, N), ma(T, N).
```

You will need to wrap this in something that ensures the length matches the length of the outer list:

```
ma(L, N) :- length(L, N), ma_1(L, N).
```

Note that there is no need to obtain separate variables and assert their equality (your dance with N and N1). Prolog will simply fail, which is what you want, if N does not have the right value. (Side note, do not use `is` for unification. The purpose of `is` is to reduce an arithmetic expression on the right side to a value and assign it to the variable on the left, e.g. `X is 2 + 3*4`.)

Another approach would be to write your actual request in a logical form and write that instead. A logical form of this request would be something like "ma(L, N) holds if N is the length of L and for all items X of L, they are lists of length N as well". This looks like so:

```
ma(L, N) :- 
    length(L, N), 
    forall(member(X, L), 
           length(X, N)).
```

This has an advantage in that no spare choice points are left around, although worrying about that is usually premature optimization.

Another approach would be to employ `maplist/N`, which has the advantage that it will give you back lists with variables. Unfortunately, `length/2` has its parameters in the wrong order so you can't do the really cute thing and just write `maplist(length(2), L)`. However, you can make a `flip/3` predicate that flips around the arguments:

```
flip(P, Y, X) :- call(P, X, Y).

ma(L, N) :- length(L, N), maplist(flip(length, N), L).
```

Or, you can import `library(yall)` and use its lambda expressions:

```
ma(L, N) :- length(L, N), maplist({N}/[X]>>length(X, N), L).
```

Both of these approaches allow solutions like these:

```
?- ma(X, N).
X = [],
N = 0 ;

X = [[_1976]],
N = 1 ;

X = [[_1982, _1988], [_1994, _2000]],
N = 2 ;

X = [[_1988, _1994, _2000], [_2006, _2012, _2018], [_2024, _2030, _2036]],
N = 3 
...
```

Comment: A maplist in place of forall would also handle `ma(L,2)`

Comment: @false I was thinking about that but I think `length/2`'s parameters are in the wrong order for `maplist(length(2), L)`. Is there another way?

Comment: @DanielLyons: yes, you could use a lambda expression. It is however a pitty that, afaik, there is no `flip` predicate.

Comment: Ehy Daniel, thanks for your answer . You use more complex predicates that I don't use. I know length/2 build in, but I must make all alone because my professor don't want that we use a predicate build in :S i tried you ma/2 but dont working with my staff, because working when you call ma ([1,2],[2,3],[3,4],X) give 2...and it s wrong, because must be fail...i will edit my question

Comment: @theantomc I have added a little wrapper to prevent the problem.